# Best practice to create absolute URLs with Zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, hyperlink

Is there a best practice for creating absolute URLs using the Zend framework? I wonder if there is some helper or if this would just be concatenating the scheme, host, etc. from the $_SERVER variable and then add the relative path generated by Zend.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

phpfour's way is OK, but you have to check for https://, ftp:// and mailto: too... :)

I prefefer having all urls root-absolute (`/files/js/jquery.js`). The "hardcore zend way" is

```
<?php 
// document root for example.com is in /htdocs 
// but application's index.php resides in /htdocs/myapp/public
echo $this->baseUrl('css/base.css'); 
//will return /myapp/public/css/base.css

echo $this->serverUrl() . $this->baseUrl('css/base.css');
//will return http://www.example.com/myapp/public/css/base.css

echo '//' . $this->getHelper('ServerUrl')->getHost() . $this->baseUrl('css/base.css');
//will return protocol relative URL //www.example.com/myapp/public/css/base.css
```

Comment: +1, it's best to use a standard approach 99% of the time - Zend Framework already includes this for you. If you need to change the URL base manually, you can also set it in the bootstrap yourself.

Comment: echo $this->serverUrl() . $this->baseUrl('cassbase.css'); (this is absolute using zend serverurl view helper)

Comment: $this->baseUrl return an URL relative to the root of the web server as stated here : http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl , TMHO this answer is wrong.

Comment: Yes, you're partly right. I try to update my answer to better reflect what will be returned.

Answer (score 13):

Without mvc

```
echo $this->serverUrl() . $this->baseUrl('cass/base.css');
```

or with mvc

```
echo  $this->serverUrl() . $this->url(array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'index'),null,true);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my applications, I keep a "baseUrl" in my application config and I assign that to registry on bootstrapping. Later I use the following View Helper to generate the URL:

```
<?php

class Zend_View_Helper_UrlMap
{
    public function UrlMap($original)
    {
        $newUrl  = $original;
        $baseUrl = Zend_Registry::get('baseUrl');

        if (strpos($newUrl, "http://") === false) {
            $newUrl = $baseUrl . $newUrl;
        }

        return $newUrl;
    }
}
```

Benefit: I can make any change on all the URLs in the view from one place.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `Zend_Registry` is pretty unnecessary. A much better approach would use `Zend_Controller_Front::setBaseUrl()` and `Zend_Controller_Front::getBaseUrl()`. That way, you can also use the included view helper so you don't have to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt use $_SERVER, I would use the values from `Zend_Controller_Request_Http::getServer($keyName);` (or the direct getters on the request object when that applies - i forget which ones are direct members of the object and which ones need to be accessed with getServer). Technically these are the exact same values, but IMO its better access it the Zend way than to use the raw PHP access. But yes catting those together should get you what you need. This is actually the way i did it for an SSL controller plugin/url helper.

There could be a better way though...

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method.

`<a href="<?php echo $this->serverUrl() . $this->url('application', ['action' => 'detail']) ?>">`