# working with zf2 to get site path in view file

Tags: php, zend-framework2

This is very silly question but I'm new to zf2

can any body please tell me how to get path like this in view file

"http://localhost/myprj/"

in zf1 I used $this->baseUrl("assets/admin/images/shared/side_shadowleft.jpg") as a src of image and I got the result but I couldn't manage it in ZF2...

I found $this->basePath();

but it returns "myprj/public" I did not need this. I need with http path I believe so it is must needed other wise I can create the constant in the index.php like this.

```
 define("SITE_PATH", $this->serverUrl()."myprj");
```

Comment: What is the structure of your project? Where assets folder is situated?

Comment: [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881254/best-practice-to-create-absolute-urls-with-zend-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it really so hard to use G**gle?

```
<?php echo $this->basePath('assets/admin/images/shared/side_shadowleft.jpg');
```

or

```
<?php echo $this->basePath()?>/assets/admin/images/shared/side_shadowleft.jpg
```

Such examples are included in the ZF2 skeleton app as well.